# How can I "extends" an attribute from directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, md-autocomplete

What I'm trying to do or know if it's possible, is extends/share/reuse or anything like this:

Passing through my directive an specific attribute that will be used in a tag inside the directive template:

`<app-autocomplete md-floating-label="Movies"></app-autocomplete>`

And inside my directive tpl:

`<md-autocomplete md-floating-label>
<!-- where md-floating-label has the value: Movies -->`

Why I want to do this? Because the md-autocomplete could be use in two different ways, having `placeholder` or `md-floating-label`. So I want to be able use one or other depending on my layout. I also want avoid the term don't repeat yourself.

If I do not use $scope, would be something like this, where also doesn't work:

`<app-autocomplete placeholder="false" md-floating-label="Cidade">`

`<md-autocomplete placeholder="placeholder" md-floating-label="mdFloatingLabel">`

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

But if your directive has no isolated scope u can use all $scope data of parent elements